# Почему при изменении текста edittext в recycleriew изменяются 3 других?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, textview

Написал код который по факту должен сохранять значения из edittext который находится в recyclerview:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewRoomViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.newRoomText.setText(newRooms.get(position).getText());

        holder.newRoomCount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                onEditTextChanged(position, s.toString());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                        String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
    public void onEditTextChanged(int position, String charSeq) {
        if (!Objects.equals(charSeq, "")) {
            widgets.put("widget" + String.valueOf(position + 1), Integer.parseInt(charSeq));
        }
    }
```

однако обновлялось несколько editext. Объясню:

Когда пользователь вводит значение в edittext с position 1, вызывается функция **onTextChanged** у позиций: 11, 14, 1 (всего 15 edittext'ов). Всегда последней идёт правильная позиция. Т.е. вместо сохранения в список значения из 1, он сохраняет ещё и для 11, 14.

Можно ли это как-либо исправить?

Comment: А как этот код нам поможет понять почему в методе `onEditTextChanged(...)` что-то не так сохраняется?

Comment: Я добавил мою функцию, однако, основной вопрос не в том, что текст не сохраняется, а в том, что функция onTextChanged вызывается 3 раза, хоть был изменён всего 1 edittext

Comment: Вам нужно в методе onViewRecycled отвязывать "слушатель" `removeTextChangedListener` иначе у вас образуется "паровозик" из "слушателей". Что я кстати и предлагал предварительно.

Comment: @Style-7 спасибо, попробую, не понял тогда о чём вы горите, извините

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это классическое поведение для Recycler'а, к сожалению.

### `О проблеме`

сама проблема заключется в том, что у Ресайклера, на самом деле, ограниченное кол-во элементов. примерно = кол-во видимых элементов на экране + 1-2 штуки запаса сверху и снизу.
и когда вы скролите ресайклер - эти элементы переиспользуются (вызывается `onBindViewHolder`)
а т.к. `addTextChangedListener` - это добавление слушателя в массив слушателей (они копятся под капотом), то и происходит такое нестандартное поведение.

### `Решение классическое`

Повесить addTextChangedListener НЕ в методе `onBindViewHolder`, а в методе `onCreateViewHolder`
`onBindViewHolder` - это метод, который вызывается каждый раз, когда элемент надо перерисовать
а вот `onCreateViewHolder` - вызывается 1 раз и сразу для всех.
в целом, хорошим тоном является даже `setOnClickListener` именно в `onCreateViewHolder`

### `Решение для варинтов "общего для всех Ресайклера"`

есть различные решения, чтобы создать 1 уникальный адаптер и скрамливать ему разные элементы. но у всех их одно общее - недоступность к методоу `onCreateViewHolder`
т.е. у нас в доступе только `onBindViewHolder`
но и тут решение красивое:
создайте ваш объект `TextWatcher` как переменную. а в `onBindViewHolder`, для вашего `EditText` повесьте слушатель фокуса.
если поле в фокусе - `addTextChangedListener(myWatcher)`
если фокус сняли - `removeTextChangedListener(myWatcher)`

Comment: Отличное решение! Но есть одна загвоздка: для работы моего кода в onTextChanged мне нужна position переменная, могу ли я её как либо получить?

Comment: @Mixadyt тогда вам нужен 2ой вариант - когда `EditText` в фокусе - `addTextChangedListener`. когда фокус снимается - `removeTextChangedListener`

Comment: но ведь тогда мне тоже нужно как либо передать в onTextChanged позицию, есть ли варианты как можно это сделать?

Comment: Извините, сглупил:) спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Mixadyt можно создать свой собственный колбэк и прокинуть его снаружи внутрь рейсайклера. а когда будете вводить в поле - дергать этот колбэк, передавая в него и строку и позицию.